# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Interface 'Laminas\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface' not found

Tags: magento2, laminas

anyone encountered this issues after upgrading from Magento 2.3.1 to 2.4.

This happened when I tried to compile the magento.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Interface 'Laminas\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface' not found in setup/src/Magento/Setup/Di/MagentoDiFactory.php:17
Stack trace:
#0 vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(444): include()
#1 vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
#2 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
#3 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call()
#4 /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(134): class_exists()
#5 setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(117): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->includeClass()
#6 setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(87): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->extract()
#7setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/ApplicationCodeGenerator.php(71): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->getList()
#8 /var/www/html/setu in /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Di/MagentoDiFactory.php on line 17
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add the content of require section in composer.json in your post? And also tell us what is your Magento 2.4 version in detail, like 2.4.5-p1.

Comment: @TuVan it is Magento 2.4.1

Comment: @TuVan i have the attatched  require section. please check.

Comment: it would be great if you paste the content in the post instead of taking a screenshot. With the content, we can easier copy it to provide the solution for you. I've shared the solution, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Note: When installing Magento project by cloning/downloading the Magento github repository because it is recommended for Magento contributors (Developers contributing to Magento Open Source). Magento recommends installing the project using Composer: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/composer.html

In your case, you should not copy the whole content of `require` section in `composer.json` from Magento github repository.

Try this solution:

1. Remove all packages which exist in `require` section in `composer.json` from Magento github repository from your `require` section in your `composer.json`.

For your case (Magento 2.4.1 https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.1/composer.json#L14):
packages in `require` section in your `composer.json` should be removed are:

```
"php": "~7.3.0||~7.4.0",
"ext-bcmath": "*",
"ext-ctype": "*",
"ext-curl": "*",
"ext-dom": "*",
"ext-gd": "*",
"ext-hash": "*",
"ext-iconv": "*",
"ext-intl": "*",
"ext-mbstring": "*",
"ext-openssl": "*",
"ext-pdo_mysql": "*",
"ext-simplexml": "*",
"ext-soap": "*",
"ext-xsl": "*",
"ext-zip": "*",
"lib-libxml": "*",
"colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file": "~1.4.1",
"colinmollenhour/cache-backend-redis": "1.11.0",
"colinmollenhour/credis": "1.11.1",
"colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract": "~1.4.0",
"composer/composer": "^1.9",
"elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "~7.7.0",
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3.3",
"laminas/laminas-captcha": "^2.7.1",
"laminas/laminas-code": "~3.4.1",
"laminas/laminas-config": "^2.6.0",
"laminas/laminas-console": "^2.6.0",
"laminas/laminas-crypt": "^2.6.0",
"laminas/laminas-db": "^2.8.2",
"laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin": "^1.0",
"laminas/laminas-di": "^2.6.1",
"laminas/laminas-eventmanager": "^3.0.0",
"laminas/laminas-feed": "^2.9.0",
"laminas/laminas-form": "^2.10.0",
"laminas/laminas-http": "^2.6.0",
"laminas/laminas-i18n": "^2.7.3",
"laminas/laminas-json": "^2.6.1",
"laminas/laminas-log": "^2.9.1",
"laminas/laminas-mail": "^2.9.0",
"laminas/laminas-mime": "^2.5.0",
"laminas/laminas-modulemanager": "^2.7",
"laminas/laminas-mvc": "~2.7.0",
"laminas/laminas-serializer": "^2.7.2",
"laminas/laminas-server": "^2.6.1",
"laminas/laminas-servicemanager": "^2.7.8",
"laminas/laminas-session": "^2.7.3",
"laminas/laminas-soap": "^2.7.0",
"laminas/laminas-stdlib": "^3.2.1",
"laminas/laminas-text": "^2.6.0",
"laminas/laminas-uri": "^2.5.1",
"laminas/laminas-validator": "^2.6.0",
"laminas/laminas-view": "~2.11.2",
"magento/composer": "1.6.0",
"magento/magento-composer-installer": ">=0.1.11",
"magento/zendframework1": "~1.14.2",
"monolog/monolog": "^1.17",
"paragonie/sodium_compat": "^1.6",
"pelago/emogrifier": "^3.1.0",
"php-amqplib/php-amqplib": "~2.10.0",
"phpseclib/mcrypt_compat": "1.0.8",
"phpseclib/phpseclib": "2.0.*",
"ramsey/uuid": "~3.8.0",
"symfony/console": "~4.4.0",
"symfony/event-dispatcher": "~4.4.0",
"symfony/process": "~4.4.0",
"tedivm/jshrink": "~1.3.0",
"tubalmartin/cssmin": "4.1.1",
"webonyx/graphql-php": "^0.13.8",
"wikimedia/less.php": "~1.8.0"
```

2. Require Magento 2.4.1 by composer:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.1 --no-update
composer update
```

3. Upgrade database:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

4. Compile the code:

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Answer (score 0):

I had about the same problem with the exact same error message. In my case I forgot to remove the setup directory of a different Magento version that is created in Magento home during composer install. After removing the setup directory and doing another composer install the compile error was gone. Hope this helps.